# Shuffle One Variable Within Group

Tags: random, dataset, stata, assign

This question is an extension of the excellent answer provided by Robert Picard here: [How to Randomly Assign to Groups of Different Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869337/how-to-randomly-assign-to-groups-of-different-sizes)

We have this dataset, which is the same as in the previous question, but adds the `year` variable:

```
sysuse census, clear
keep state region pop
order state pop region
decode region, gen(reg)
replace reg="NCntrl" if reg=="N Cntrl"
drop region
gen year=20 
replace year=30 if _n>15
replace year=40 if _n>35
```

If I just wanted to re-randomly assign `reg`'s across all observations (without regard to group), I could implement the answer to the previous post:

```
tempfile orig
save `orig'
keep reg
rename reg reg_new
set seed 234
gen double u = runiform()
sort u reg_new
merge 1:1 _n  using `orig', nogen
```

How would the code be modified so that `reg` is shuffled, but only within `year`? For example, there are 15 observations where `year==20`. These observations should be shuffled separately than the other years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shuffling one variable doesn't require any file choreography. This can probably be shortened:

```
sysuse auto, clear 
set seed 2803 

gen double shuffle = runiform() 

* example 1 
sort shuffle 
gen long which = _n 
sort mpg 
gen mpg_new = mpg[which] 
list which mpg* 

* example 2 
bysort foreign (shuffle) : gen long which2 = _n 
bysort foreign (mpg) : gen mpg2 = mpg[which2] 
list which2 mpg mpg2, sepby(foreign)
```

All that said, I think `sample` does this so long as you specify the same sample size as the number in the dataset. It's overkill because you get all the variables.

Comment: You are right Nick, this is a better approach. I would caution that `which` should be of type `long` if the dataset is large

Comment: @RobertPicard Naturally I agree. I've edited the code so that the example is better.